# Elegant way to read this data into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking at the text file posted here since I can't find a cleaner table of atmospheric C02 concentration history anywhere:

> https://data.giss.nasa.gov/modelforce/ghgases/Fig1A.ext.txt

I'm trying to figure out how to read this file into pandas without having to do awkward text editor manipulations first. Is there a way to do it?

The way I'd do it in the editor is by first cutting out all the words from the text file, then use read_table but I'd have to provide some instruction that it interprets the data in the order of year, ppm, year, ppm, etc. I don't know how to do that and also can't help but wonder if there's a smart way to read the original file with python automatically recognizing the offending words as words and ignoring them?

Comment: Most elegant is a matter of opinion.  IMO the most elegant way is to create a new text file.

Comment: May I ask what editor you'd use to wrap the repeated (year, ppm) sets of columns? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`pandas.read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html), that is reasonably straight forward:

**Code:**

```
df = pd.read_fwf(
    'https://data.giss.nasa.gov/modelforce/ghgases/Fig1A.ext.txt', 
    header=None, skiprows=5, nrows=50,
    colspecs=[( 8, 12), (14, 20), (28, 32), (34, 40),
              (48, 52), (54, 60), (68, 72), (74, 80)])

years = np.concatenate([df[i].values for i in range(0, 8, 2)])
temps = np.concatenate([df[i].values for i in range(1, 8, 2)])
df = pd.DataFrame(temps, index=years, columns=['temps']).dropna()
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
         temps
1850.0  285.20
1851.0  285.10
1852.0  285.00
1853.0  285.00
1854.0  284.90
...        ...
2007.0  383.37
2008.0  385.46
2009.0  386.95
2010.0  389.21
2011.0  391.15

[162 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: @theverge, you are very welcome.  However, on SO the very best way to say thanks is to upvote *any* questions or answers you find useful.  And on your questions, if one of the answers is a good fit for your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer.  See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for guidelines.

Comment: Thanks. I can't upvote answers yet due to the weird SO system where one has to somehow prove that one is worthy of upvoting first. If I accept your answer and a simpler one comes along, will I still be able to accept that one too?

Comment: The Reputation limit for voting is a bit annoying, but is neccesary to keep sock puppets and spammers at bay.  As for the accepted answer, you can change your accepted answer at any time and as many times as you want.  Which can be occasionally annoying on my end, when I have had an answer accepted and unaccepted multiple time in a day.  But  other than ping-ponging,  I would encourage to change the accepted answer if a better one came along, Cheers, and welcome to Stackoverflow.